# Tensorflow model is throwing up InvalidArgumentError During Prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I am trying to get predictions by AI on individual pictures, but I am getting `invalidargument` error, the dataset is unbatched, and I am iterating over it per image, but whenever I set batch size bigger then 1 problem gets fixed, sadly I can't get individual predictions with batch sizes rather then arithmetic mean between all values, can anyone help me out to fix this error?

This is code:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import Xception
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Flatten, Dropout, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
import cv2
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from tqdm import tqdm
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback
import keras
import shutil
import pathlib

cluster_resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(cluster_resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(cluster_resolver)
strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(cluster_resolver)

DATADIR2 = '../input/testmanuscriptdatabase/databaseDEUTCHE'
CATEGORIES1 = [1340,  1376,  1411,  1432,  1454,  1470,  1488,  1517,  1542,  1574,
    1343,  1377,  1412,  1434,  1455,  1472,  1490,  1518,  1547,  1578,
    1347,  1378,  1413,  1442,  1458,  1473,  1495,  1521,  1550,  1581,
    1351,  1384,  1415,  1445,  1459,  1474,  1499,  1526,  1552,  1583,
    1356,  1393,  1420,  1446,  1460,  1478,  1500,  1528,  1554,  1586,
    1361,  1396,  1422,  1447,  1462,  1479,  1503,  1532,  1556,  1588,
    1365,  1399,  1428,  1449,  1466,  1480,  1506,  1535,  1561,  1593,
    1370,  1406,  1430,  1450,  1467,  1481,  1510,  1536,  1565,
    1335,  1374,  1410,  1431,  1451,  1469,  1487,  1513,  1537,  1570,]

dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(DATADIR2, image_size=(299, 299), batch_size = None)

def relabel_map(image, label):
    # Define your relabeling logic here, for example:
    new_label = 0
    for i in range (89):
        if label == i:
            new_label = CATEGORIES1[i]
    
    new_label = (new_label - 1330)//30

    return image, new_label

dataset = dataset.map(relabel_map)

@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class Custom_MSECE_Loss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
        cce_loss = cce(y_true, y_pred)
        arg_y_pred = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
        arg_y_true=tf.math.argmax(y_true, axis=1)
        arg_y_pred=tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
        arg_y_true=tf.cast(y_pred, tf.float32)
        # if tf.abs(arg_y_true - arg_y_pred) >= 10:
        #     weight = 3
        # elif tf.abs(arg_y_true - arg_y_pred) >= 5:
        #     weight = 2
        # elif tf.abs(arg_y_true - arg_y_pred) >= 2:
        #     weight = 1
        # else:
        #     weight = 0.5
        absolute_errors = tf.abs(y_true - y_pred)
        weight = tf.where(absolute_errors >= 10,5.0,tf.where(absolute_errors >= 5,2.5,tf.where(absolute_errors >= 2, 1.0, 0.5)))
        return tf.reduce_mean(weight*tf.square(arg_y_true - arg_y_pred)+cce_loss)

with strategy.scope():
    baseModel = Xception(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(299, 299, 3))
    baseModel.trainable=False
    # Model With Transfer Learning From Xception
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(baseModel) # Xception
    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='leaky_relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5)) # Dropout To Reduce Overfitting
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='leaky_relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(27, activation='softmax'))  # Final Dense Layer - Can Output 27 Classes

# Learning Rate - Determines the size of weight updates during optimization
# Beta_1 - Controls The Contribution Of Past Gradients To The Optimization
# Beta_2 - Controls The Contribution Of Past Squared Gradients To The Optimization
# Epsilon Prevents Division By Zero For Numerical Stability
# Decay - Adjusts Learning Rate Over Time; Set To 0 For No Decay
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

# Cmpile The Model
    model.compile(optimizer= optimizer, loss=Custom_MSECE_Loss(), metrics=['accuracy'])

model.build((None, 299, 299, 3))

model.load_weights('/kaggle/working/best_model_big_epoch4_valacc40.h5')

predictions = []
labels = []
for image, label in dataset:
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    #print(image.shape)
    prediction = model.predict(image)
    predictions.append(prediction)
    labels.append(label)
```

and this is error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
...
Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [1,27] != values[1].shape = [0,27]
     [[{{node Rank/packed}}]] [Op:__inference_one_step_on_data_distributed_17620]
```